# How to have a reference to an extra factory

Tags: magento2, factory

I'm trying to have a reference to a model factory to load an object on desire.
I just added a parameter to the constructor, but it generates an error:

(The parent constructor doesn't have the parameter: **"\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory"**)

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument
>   5 passed to Amaj\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmenu::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory, none given, called
>   in
>   D:\ProgramFiles\wamp64\www\parastoo\var\generation\Amaj\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmenu\Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   D:\ProgramFiles\wamp64\www\parastoo\app\code\Amaj\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmenu.php
>   on line 33

What am I doing wrong? please help

**Source code:**

```
<?php

namespace Amaj\MegaMenu\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

/**
 * Html page top menu block
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

    protected $categoryFactory;


    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param NodeFactory $nodeFactory
     * @param TreeFactory $treeFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        TreeFactory $treeFactory,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory, $treeFactory, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to remove `var/generation` folder?

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh: Thanks. That was the problem. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a module, we should care about generation files under `var/generation`. Sometimes, we meet:

> Recoverable Error: Argument  passed to __construct() must be an
>   instance of

We should remove `var/generation` folder.